# how to use military time validation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate military times. I want to accept times like 19:25, but not 1925. My current expression does not accept times with `:`.  What am i missing here?

```
([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]
```

Comment: You're *missing* exactly what you are asking for ..

Comment: `<RANT>` this is not *military time* - it's the **24-hour time format**, used by the majority of earthlings in their daily life... only the US and a few other oddball countries still insist on using 2x12-hours for their time... `</RANT>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accept times without colons: `(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))[0-5][0-9]` (You're missing a set of parentheses.)

If you want to accept times with colons: `(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]`

If you want colons to be optional: `(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):?[0-5][0-9]`

Comment: i have tried but did not work.  I put 23:50 and it did not work then i put 2350 then it took it.  I need to have the colon like this 23:50. thanks